# Subset misses values

Tags: subset

I'm pretty new to coding, but it seems that my subset is missing values and I'm wondering what i am doing wrong. So, I have a data frame called «df_envel» with 4 colums : Elevation, distance, profil, date. I am trying to subset this dataframe to get only values that equals -0.1 m. I have tried multiple subset methods but all methods misses some -0.1 values and put some NA's instead. Here's the subset code lines I tried which all returns to the same number of values:

Here is my code:

```
f<- df_envel[which(df_envel$Elevation=='-0.1'),]

f<- df_envel %>% filter(Elevation == '-0.1')

f<- subset(df_envel, Elevation %in% '-0.1')
```

Does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I finally resolved it by changing the data frame into a matrix, change it to numeric, subset and than turn it back into a data frame. I don't really know why it worked, but it did!

```
df_envel <- as.matrix(df_envel) 
df_envel[,c(1,2)] <- as.numeric(df_envel[,c(1,2)])
f <- df_envel[ which(df_envel[,'Elevation']=='0'),]
f <- as.data.frame(f)
```

Comment: Well, finally I encountered the same problem in another code and the sketchy trick I did before doesn't work anymore. If ever someone as an idea of how I can solve the problem it would be appreciated!

Comment: The solution was : 

mytol <- 0.05 (or whatever tolerance you need)

df_envel[ which(df_envel$Elevation < (-0.1 + mytol) & df_envel$Elevation > (-0.1 - mytol),]